# List performance optimization

Tags: algorithm, scala, graph

Is there any chance to optimise next line of code:

```
 val adj: Array[ListBuffer[Int]] = Array.fill(n)( ListBuffer[Int]())
...
..

 val sourceVertexes = inGraph.zipWithIndex.filter(v => a.zipWithIndex.exists(r => r._2 != v._2 && r._1.exists(f => f == v._2) )
```

inGraph - array of vertexes with direction/link to other vertexes.
inGraph size could be, say, say 10000 vertexes.

I am trying to find list of sources (list of vertexes with out any in-comming edges)

```
  val adj: Array[List[Int]] = Array.fill(n)( List[Int]())
```

Comment: What is `a` in the first line of code?

Comment: Just updated question. I would more suspect that I should change data type from ( List or ListBuffer) to something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make it faster by using a more efficient algorithm. 
What code does now is basically:

```
for each vertex:
    for each edge:
        if egde goes to vertex:
            discard it
```

It has an `O(n * m)` time complexity in the worst case (where `m` is the number of edges and `n` is the number of vertices).

Here is a solution which is linear in the size of the graph:

```
noIncoming = a hash set with all vertices (or just a boolean array)
for each edge:
    if edge is not a loop:
       noIncoming.remove(edge.desitination) // or we can put a mark in a boolean array
```

The `noIncoming` is the set of vertices with no incoming edges.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it working this way. However, I've decided to go for other solution. I've created other array of lists to keep list of incomming edges which gave me liners time search!